# Meteor Iron Router Error Slack Clone

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I was creating a slack clone with meteor using this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-slack-clone-in-meteor-js-part-4-channels-and-chat-rooms

I keep getting this error thrown at me:

> Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?'

Here is the code I have:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'app'
});

Router.route('/:channel', function () {
  Session.set('channel', this.params.channel);
  this.render('messages');
})

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.redirect('/general');
});
```

Comment: Is this your entire router js? Do you have any routes with onBeforeAction?

Comment: Yes, looks like you should show bigger part of code. Maybe onBeforeAction is in some other place of code?